# Magento set final price for product listing page

Tags: magento

How can we   set final price for product listing page although,i have made some changes in price model 
and in  product detail page it our custom final price is reflecting but in listing page it is displaying page it is showing old price .

Answer (score 1):

Maybe magento gets price with another function, check in this template file:

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/price.phtml
```